# Project an environment texture to a ground plane that updates with the camera FOV

Tags: vector-mapping

I'm trying to project my scenes environment texture to a ground plane so that when viewed from the camera it matches the environment, but also updates when the camera is moved or rotated.

Like a projection mapping of sorts that's linked to the environment texture and the cameras FOV. I think it might have something to do with the vector transform node, but I'm struggling to get it to match up with the environment and update as necessary.

The image below is my node setup and also shows the environment being projected onto the ground plane. Thanks in advance.

[image: project environment to plane]

Comment: Camera/UV projection modifier should work out of the box with your setup. Alternatively: [Camera projection without generating UV's?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121210/camera-projection-without-generating-uvs)