# How can I get a volume shader to use a texture with camera projection UVs?

Tags: texturing, uv

In the linked blend file I have a box with a volume shader with a texture cut out coming from an image file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LpxQXZRF66g3nVZw7lU8kgAVEVJY9Ant/view?usp=sharing

There are two examples in the shader network of the cube geo. One that work with the texture mapped through object space and another where the texture goes through a camera projection UVs. The later doesn't work.

How can I get the volume texture to work with the projection UVs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So apparently Volumes shader don't support UV coordinates. So I generated the projection vector using this method:

[Camera projection without generating UV's?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121210/camera-projection-without-generating-uvs)

Comment: It's not that surprising, UVs are a 2D representation of a 3D surface. Volume is, by definition, a volume, not a surface. UVs would have "nothing" to define a volume, only the surface that encloses it.