# 'Project from view' issue Blender 2.93

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, vector-mapping

I am trying to get the background image projected onto the plane below. From the UV editor window, the UVs looks perfectly fine as I want it to be and as it should be, but the textures on the mesh Do Not Match. I don't know Why!

[image: UV Project Problem Image]

**I Have already Applied Rotation, Loc, Scale to the plane**
I also tried using the UV Project modifier, got same results.

Comment: Try to add more subdivisions to the plane(Right click subdivide in edit mode)

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't seem to work for me, the texture is still Way off

Comment: If you subdivide the the plane, you have to unwrap it again so that the new geometry is taken into account in the unwrapping. Then this will work, I'll edit my answer to give an example for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UV Projection not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/217908/uv-projection-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

What doesn't work here is that you have a rectangular plane, where the opposite faces are exactly the same size and you're changing them to a perspectively distorted UV map. The camera's view also distorts the rectangluar shape of the plane, so it's double distorted.

Don't quote me on that, I'm not going for physically correct explanations... the point is, to achieve what you want to do, you don't necessarily need UV mapping, you can use the *Window* output of the *Texture Coordinate* node in the *Shader Editor*, or choose *Window* if you set the *Vector* in the *Material Properties*.

[image: uv mapping window]

If you want to use UV mapping you need more geometry to calculate the distortion correctly, so you have to subdivide the plane as @Emir suggests in his comment. But then you have to unwrap it again to project this new geometry. If it still doesn't work, the subdivisions were not enough. The *Window* method I described above doesn't need additional geometry.

But here is an example to show you why it doesn't work without enough geometry or not unwrapping it again after subdividing. On the left is the plane with just four vertices. If you now subdivide it, the plane will be cut evenly subdivision is the same size, according to the original geometry. But if you don't project again from view, the UV is a 2D workspace. Each edge is not a perspective representation, so the cuts will simply divide all edges evenly according to their 2D length. Only if you unwrap it again with *Project from View*, the proportional subdivision will be taken into account.

[image: uv unwrapping geometry]