# Unwrapping with "Project from view" gets weird results

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I have a simple plane stretching into the distance (picture 1), and I want to unwrap this using the "project from view" option so the texture will perfectly match the footage except, when I unwrap it using that method, the UV squares are absolutely everywhere and the texture (obviously) doesn't match (picture 2). **Why is this happening?**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Frequent issue here .. People usually use Simple subdivision to dense topology also avoid geometry behind camera ... but it wouldn't be perfect anyway ... Use camera projection shader instead  UV from view ... my favourite solution... https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/226821/2214

Comment: Here is several solutions, but not the best ones from my opinion :) https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/213542/2214
https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/217908/2214
https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/229935/2214