# Unwrap doesn't show correct results

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I have unwrapped a UV plane with "Project From View" (pic 1 & 2) and it unwrapped the plane perfectly except, even though in the UV Editor the UV looks perfectly positioned (pic 2), the texture result it stretched and warbled (pic 3). **Why is this happening?** I haven't messed with the texture at all in the nodes or anything.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Subdivide your plane and see if it works better

Comment: Seems to me you already asked here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239560/ and in second comment I attached several links to this issue with explaination ... if there is something specific you didnt understood be more specific instead of duplicating same Q

Comment: @moonboots If you post that as an actual comment, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @vklidu It's a bit different in that before, the UVs were all distorted. In this one, their all on the correct place, the result on the actual object is warbled.

Comment: Yes, but in both cases distortion can be solved by any of the four solutions provided in mentioned link or comment in your first Q to this topic (subdivision included ... and as mentioned by moonboots - subdivision make it just less noticeable, to solve it completely is better to use different method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quad is actually made of 2 tris in Blender. If you project an image as texture it will tend to deform this image. To avoid that just subdivide your plane until the deformation is not noticeable anymore.