# UV Project Modifier project only to visible surfaces

Tags: uv, image

Is there a way, using the UV Project Modifier to project an image to only the visible surfaces of an object?
Let's say you have a cube. You can only see max 3 of the 6 sides at a time. Now if you use a UV Project modifier all 6 sides will have the image texture on them even tho 3 are not directly visible to the camera. Is there a way to fix this issue?
I could manually create a UV map by going into camera view, selecting everything that is visible to the camera and UV-project from view, but I need it working automatically since I want to use it in a script.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Most likely because the *Image Texture* node of your material is set to 'Repeat' (it's the default), if you set it to 'Clip' it should work fine. Doesn't it?

Comment: No it is set to clip. This results in the surfaces outside the camera view being black/transparent not textures but doesn't affect the surfaces that are behind other surfaces in the camera view. Thank you anyways for your suggestion!

Comment: Check last image with blend example included https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/121372/2214 ... still working for me.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you so much @vklidu