# Projecting multiple equirectangular images inside mesh

Tags: texturing, materials

I am doing a project where I have images taken from a panoramic camera inside of a physical object that I have modelled in Blender. I can project these onto a simplified object without problems using an image texture.

The object is a bit more complex and so will need multiple images taken from inside. Is there a way to project these images radially from the locations where the camera would have been? I know I can connect the image positions to an object, but it is not clear to me how the image is tethered to the object position.

If this is possible, how do I manage the overlap areas?

Comment: Possibly related : 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/71334/29586, 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/121372/29586, 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/80007/29586 (although this last one won't cater for overlap, since you'll have aditional light from the lamp)